# python pandas change data frame cells using iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to modify two values in a single row of a data frame. However, I get an exception, which I am unable to explain the reason for.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2,3), index=['one', 'two'],
                          columns=list('ABC'))

In [4]: df['Z'] = list(range(len(df.index)))

In [5]: df.head(1)
Out[5]: 
            A         B         C  Z
one  0.977917  0.734311  0.069476  0

In [6]: df.iloc[0] = dict(B=3.5, Z=10)
```

> /home/rajatgirotra/tools/miniconda2/envs/shriram/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.pyc
>   in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
>       525 
>       526                     if len(labels) != len(value):
>   --> 527                         raise ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value '
>       528                                          'when setting with an iterable')
>       529
>
> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an
>   iterable

Is this way incorrect? How can I easily modify one or more cell values in the same row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@jezrael's `df.iloc[0] = pd.Series(d)` is my preference.

But you can also use `pd.DataFrame.update` and wrap your dictionary in a `pd.DataFrame`

```
df.update(pd.DataFrame(dict(B=3.5, Z=10), ['one']))

df

            A         B         C     Z
one  0.339970  3.500000  0.528206  10.0
two  0.553827  0.117207  0.784605   1.0
```

---

While I'm at it, here is a creative way using `pd.DataFrame.set_value` and a list comprehension.  This has the advantage of no overhead building the dataframe and notice the `dtype` is preserved on column `'Z'`

```
[df.set_value('one', k, v) for k, v in dict(B=3.5, Z=10).items()];

df

            A         B         C   Z
one  0.099669  3.500000  0.248170  10
two  0.604340  0.305114  0.897305   1
```

---

Not that it matters all that much, but this is the timing over the tiny data sample

```
%timeit [df.set_value('one', k, v) for k, v in dict(B=3.5, Z=10).items()];
%timeit df.update(pd.DataFrame(dict(B=3.5, Z=10), ['one']))
%timeit df.iloc[0] = pd.Series(dict(B=3.5, Z=10))

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.29 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 402 µs per loop
```

Comment: Yes! "df.iloc[0] = pd.Series(d)" looks more compact. I was using an "dict()" instead of a Series on the right hand side of the assignment which didn't work for me!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need select only columns by keys of dict by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), else get `NaN`s:

```
d = dict(B=3.5, Z=10)
df.loc[df.index[0], d.keys()] = pd.Series(d)
print (df)
            A         B         C     Z
one  0.062352  3.500000  0.225811  10.0
two  0.655920  0.386443  0.063906   1.0
```

```
df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_indexer(d.keys())] = pd.Series(d)
print (df)
            A         B         C     Z
one  0.422479  3.500000  0.951087  10.0
two  0.097426  0.702746  0.257591   1.0
```

---

```
df.loc[df.index[0]] = pd.Series(d)
print (df)
            A         B         C     Z
one       NaN  3.500000       NaN  10.0
two  0.050399  0.917007  0.951725   1.0
```

```
df.iloc[0] = pd.Series(d)
print (df)
          A         B         C     Z
one     NaN  3.500000       NaN  10.0
two  0.5356  0.844221  0.023227   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks.. However I need the second behavior only (to set all other cells to NaN). For some reason, i get an exception.

Comment: What kind of exception? Problem is with sample data?